# Map function displaying each character as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have some strings in an array which is in the form of Exit Survey [hr.exitinterview], Certificate [hr.certificate], Recommendation Letter [hr.recommendation] I need to extract only hr.exitinterview, hr.certificate, hr.recommendation from the existing string and add another string https://somelink/hr.exitinterview, https://somelink/hr.certificate, https://somelink/hr.recommendation to every substring and return them to another function as an array. I have tried it using substring and was able to extract the data between `[]`, but when I tried to append the contents of the array with `https://somelink/` using the `map` function, even though I able to append it, its displaying each character as separate contents of the array i.e `[h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,s,o,m,e,l,i,n,k,/,h,r,.,e,x,i,t,i,n,t,e,r,v,i,e,w,h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,s,o,m,e,l,i,n,k,/,h,r,.,c,e,r,t,i,f,i,c,a,t,e,h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,s,o,m,e,l,i,n,k,/,h,r,.,r,e,c,o,m,m,e,n,d,a,t,i,o,n]`. Instead of `[https://somelink/hr.exitinterview, https://somelink/hr.certificate, https://somelink/hr.recommendation]` May I know what is wrong with the code, I am still learning JS, please ignore if its a stupid question.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var currentTime = new Date();
Logger.log('currentTime:'+ currentTime);
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = data[i][7];
    var links = extract(checkbox);
    Logger.log('New links: ' + links);
  }
}

function extract(data) {
  var lengthOfData = [ data.length];
  if (lengthOfData > 0) {
    var fullLink = extractLinks(data);
  }
  if (fullLink.length > 0) {
    return fullLink;
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
  return -1;
}

function extractLinks(link) {
  var extractedLinks = [];
  var fullLink = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    link[i] = JSON.stringify(link[i]);
    extractedLinks.push(link[i].substring(link[i].lastIndexOf("[")+1,link[i].lastIndexOf("]")));
    fullLink = extractedLinks.map(function(a) { return "https://somelink/" + a; }).join(", ");
    Logger.log('fullLink: ' + fullLink);
  }
  return (fullLink);
}
```

Comment: What does checkbox contain? `lengthOfData` will always be > 0 (you assign a single element array).  'fullLink` will always be > 0.

Comment: Checkbox contains Exit Survey [hr.exitinterview], Certificate [hr.certificate], Recommendation Letter [hr.recommendation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop in the function extractLinks should close before 'fullLink = ...'

Also you can match the string between brackets using a regular expression (but this is a matter of taste. Finally, the final `.join(", ")` makes your function return a string, not an array.

The following modified function worked for me, and returns an array of strings

```js
function extractLinks(link) {
  var extractedLinks = [];
  var fullLink = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    link[i] = JSON.stringify(link[i]);
    extractedLinks.push(link[i].match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]);
    }
  fullLink = extractedLinks.map(function(a) { return "https://somelink/" + a; })
  Logger.log('fullLink: ' + fullLink);
  return (fullLink);
}
```